# Why is my MacbookPro 2017 Crashing?

Tags: macbook-pro

My MacBook Pro 2017 under heavy loads (gaming, rendering videos in Camtasia, recording screen casts with OBS, etc.).

[**Here's a video of it**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9CpTidCasI&feature=youtu.be)

It keeps crashing and it gives me what I call the screen of black death from Apple:

[image].

Or my games will simply shut down when playing in Windows 10

I notice when it crashes when I run OBS, the cores and other areas don't seem to be overheated the instant it crashes.

When I bought this PC I was able to render video and play games with no problem, even at the same time...but after about 4 months it's now crashing whenever you put any intensive load on it period.

I've also heard a weird buzzing noise as if a robot were to die when it crashes sometimes.  That noise doesn't happen often but has when it crashes in Windows.

It's crashing in both windows 10 and OS X High Sierra, doesn't matter.  I've dual booted it with bootcamp.

Already ran a diagnostic (where you reboot, press D and whatever) and also they ran a light diagnostics test in the Apple store.  They said next step is for me to have to bring it in for a few days, where they run a heavy diagnostics on it for 5 hours.

Also opened the bottom and took a can duster and cleaned out the fans and vents.

This sucks cause I'm a programmer and it sucks because I just paid 4k for this fing laptop.  My Macbook 20-15 started to do this last year in fact!  And that's why I bought this one!  It's weird, my macbook 2015 isn't crashing anymore after turning it on after about a year, my kids are playing minecraft on it just fine but about 6 months ago that PC was crashing all the time even after I had reinstalled OS X. I don't know, I give up.

So is this normal?  I've seen it spike even over 200 degrees on the cores and I'm not even doing any rendering or gaming right now in OS X.  I'm just doing Chrome granted I have a lot of tabs open but no hard core streaming, rendering, or playing games.

**Here's what that looks like**:

[image]

Don't know if this is typical but I see 210 threads for kernal_task:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troubleshooting is a process of elimination and usually requires some patience, so taking up the Apple Store offer may be a good way to proceed. However, before doing that there's a few more troubleshooting steps you can take.

To start with I would boot your Mac into Safe Mode and determine if it still displays this behaviour.

**Boot into Safe Mode**

Follow these steps to boot your Mac into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your MacBook Pro
2. Restart your MacBook Pro
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window (**NOTE:** If you have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice).
5. Take a note of what happens (i.e. does it still crash etc while in Safe Mode)
6. Exit Safe Mode by restarting your Mac as normal
7. Test again to see if it still crashes when booted normally

If you find that the problem still exists in Safe Mode, you can also try resetting the System Management Controller to see what difference, if any, that makes.

**Reset the SMC**

To reset the SMC, follow these steps:

1. Shut down your MacBook Pro
2. For 10 seconds, press and hold at the same time the <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>control</kbd><kbd>option</kbd> keys (on the **left** side of the **built-in** keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
3. After 10 seconds let go of all keys and the power button
4. Turn your MacBook Pro back on with the power button

After your MBP reboots, test to see if you can still get your temps to spike over 200 degrees etc (however, see my note on temperature below).

**A note on temperature**

Finally, MBP models *usually* range from about 40ºC (104ºF) to 100ºC (212ºF) depending on whether the CPU is idle or under load. CPU temps (just like ambient temperatures) typically have a bearing on GPU temps too, especially within the extremely confined spaces of a MacBook Pro.

If you'd like, you can refer to the [Intel Mac Temperature Database](https://www.intelmactemp.com/list) to see the various temperature ranges reported by users. You can also filter the list by model etc.

---

**UPDATE**

Now that you've updated your question a few times and have uploaded the YouTube video, I feel taking it into the Apple Store to look at is the best way to go. The main reasons for this are:

- Having problems in both Safe Mode and while booted normally is a strong indicator to some sort of hardware issue
- Likewise, having problems when booted into either macOS or Windows 10 is also indicative that this is OS independent (and therefore most likely a hardware issue)
- The various display glitches apparent in your YouTube video stringly imply a GPU and/or Logic Board problem

All of the above would require a visit to Apple. **Obviously, prior to doing so, make sure you have a current backup of all your data.**

If you did want to try one more thing prior to visting Apple, that would be doing a full fresh installation of macOS (to the earliest version that shipped with your MBP - you can do this by using the <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> keyboard shortcut to reinstall the **macOS that came with your Mac**) and testing to see whether you have any issues **prior to installing anything else**. If not, go about installing OBS and see if that runs okay. If so, then go about creating your BootCamp Windows installation to see if that causes a problem.

However, if it was me, I'd plan for the visit to Apple. That is, do your backup, make alternative arrangements for a few days, and get Apple to do a full hardware diagnostic.

Comment: thanks.  I noticed if I try to screen record now with either camtasia or OBS it crashes consistently within a minute.  It's bad.  I'll try out safe mode and report ack.

Comment: also tried resetting the SMC but no luck.  It doesn't seem to be crashing when temps are real high actually now that I monitored it again.

Comment: Yes, please report back after you've tested Safe Mode. In the meantime I've edited my answer to *actually* answer the bit about temperatures.

Comment: safe mode is even more sluggish after I fire up OBS. I'm about to post a video of it, so look for that in a few minutes, I'll post a youtube vid

Comment: I've already taken it to the apple store they ran basic diagnostics.  Next step they said is to have me bring it in for a full day diagnostic where they run their tool for like 5 hours or something like that.  But that's really bad, I'm a programmer this is my only PC, and I just paid 4k for this thing 6 mo ago!

Comment: I added my vid of it in the original post now.

Comment: I have my suspicions about High Sierra

Comment: I've updated my answer. As an aside, Safe Mode does often take longer to boot.

Comment: Any idea how to get the earliest version?

Comment: Just updated my answer.

Comment: "The various display glitches apparent in your YouTube video stringly imply a GPU and/or Logic Board problem".  If you mean the screen tearing at login, that's normal.  Apple: "Your screen might also "blink" or "tear" during login when your Mac is started in safe mode."  Also look under "Some features aren't available in safe mode." https://support.apple.com/HT201262